# Deleted join of simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology

Give an example of simplicial complex $K$ such that the [deleted join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(topology)#Deleted_join) of $K$ is homeomorphic with
$S^1\times [0,1]$, i.e:

$$K^{*^2}_{\bigtriangleup}\cong S^1\times [0,1]$$

Comment: What is the deleted simplicial joint of a complex?

Comment: Google returns 0 external hits when you search for "deleted joint" and "simplicial complex".

Comment: Let $K$ be a
simplicial complex. The deleted join of $K$ has the vertex set $V(K)\times[2]$, and it is given by

$$ =\{F_1\cup^{+} F_2 : F_1, F_2\in K, F_1\cap F2 =\emptyset$$ where  $F_1\cup^{+} F_2 = (F_1\times\{1\})\cup (F_2\times\{2\})$.

Comment: I would have voted to close this as unclear if there wasn't a bounty on this question. Please add any necessary details to the question (not in comments) and explain any uncommon notation and/or definitions.

Comment: HINT: I would try using the Topological Radon Theorem and Bier Spheres.

Answer (score 1):

A triangular graph (the one-skeleton of a 2-complex) will suffice. It is easier to see if you draw the top layer with each if its vertices aligned in between the opposite pair of vertices on the bottom layer.